How can I show notification actions by default
I am developing an app with react native and expo-notifications. The notifications have 2 notification buttons that are shown once the user long-presses the notification.
Is it possible for those actions/buttons to be shown by default without the user having to long press the notification?
I am willing to write a native plugin for it to work, but so far I haven't found anything that would suggest it being possible.

No, revealing actions always requires a long press
